# prevent refresh fragment when switch between fragments

Tags: android-fragments

I have two fragments:

```
public static void openWhatsNewFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    defaultTransaction(fragmentManager)
            .replace(R.id.fragment_holder, new FeedFragment())
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}

public static void openBookmarksFragment(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    defaultTransaction(fragmentManager)
            .replace(R.id.fragment_holder, new BookmarkFragment())
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
}
```

as the title, i dont want my fragments refresh when i switch.
PS: sorry for bad English.

Answer (score 1):

`FragmentTransaction.replace()` always replaces the current fragment. So, the view will always be recreated when you replace a fragment. It is your job to keep the data needed into a Bundle by implementing `onSavedInstanceState()` and then retrieve the data into `onCreateView()`.